# Servers and data handling for a tiny "app"

Tags: php, mysql, api, server-side

I have a question that I hope is appropriate to ask on this site. I know it is specified more towards actual code related questions, but I'm kind of lost.

First off, the "app" I am developing Swift is super simple, just some basic forms. The user will submit a couple strings of data and all is well. My question is basically what do I do for a server?

From what I have researched, I need to make an API and use languages like PHP and MYSQL to interact with the server and client, that all makes sense.

But what do I do for the actual server itself? Do I literally need to have my own server or can I approach this like if I was building a website and just for example: use a go-daddy web-server that I can buy a domain name for? Super noob question I am sure but I have very limited knowledge on this.

All I need is just need some clarification on how to approach server-side stuff.

Thanks anyone for any responses.

Comment: You need to ask yourself a few questions.  1. How secure does this data need to be.  2. How reliable does the server need to be.  3. How many users are you anticipating.  4. How quickly do you want to be able to scale.  5. Will you need to run any server side application that needs to be installed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I think maybe I should get more to the fundamentals. Honestly at this point in time this is just an experiment/test for now.  Those questions are extremely important but right now I just want to simply have ONE instance of this prototype app send data to a server of any kind and then have the data sent back. I just need to know how to establish this "prototype" server for the test.  If I decide to actually publish a more developed app, all of these questions will definitely be on the top of my list.

Comment: If its just a prototype you can set up a server on computer as long as you are on the same network you can connect to it.

Comment: Awesome I will look into that for my first tests! but, lets say I wanted to access it from a different network though, is there a similar "protoytpe" solution for that? Sorry for the noob questions, I'm pretty new to this side of things.  Also if you happen to know of any good resources that could give me some direction that would be immensely useful.

Comment: You could go with any basic hosting solution ($5-$10 a month) for what you are asking for, just remember you get what you pay for.